# Writing less code in ADO.NET (wrapper classes)

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, wrapper, sqlclient

So I'm pretty new to C# in general, but I have a basic knowledge of the language at the moment.

When accessing an SQL database, I've decided that using ADO.NET (SqlClient seems to be the best way to do it, and I have managed to get it working, including using queries.
My issue is that as soon as I start to query the database more often, I seem to just be rewriting very similar code over and over again (which is obviously bad practice).
It's clear that I need to make some sort of class that handles my use of ADO.NET (SqlClient) so that I cant just type something like the following:

```
DatabaseConnection.Query("SELECT * FROM tblProducts");
```

… instead of...

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString)) // cnnString was defined earlier in the code
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProductType FROM tblProductTypes", cnn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cnn.Open();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    cboFilterTypes.DataSource = dt;
    cboFilterTypes.DisplayMember = "ProductType";
    cboFilterTypes.ValueMember = "ProductType";
    cnn.Close();
}
```

So I think I need to make a class wrapper (at least that's what I believe it is called), but I'm not too sure on how to go about doing it. Does anyone have any suggestions or tricks that I can use?

*To be clear, I am not wanting to use the entity framework or anything like that which is built on ADO.NET - I've tried to entity framework and have decided there are too many drawbacks.*

Comment: You might want to check out [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) as it handles a lot of the boilerplate code of ADO.Net for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking with your request for a 'wrapper' you could simply make a static helper method to handle the call to the database such as

```
    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
    {
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString)) // cnnString was defined earlier in the code
    {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
            result = new DataTable();
            cnn.Open();
            result.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            cnn.Close();
     }
return result;
    }
```

You could then call this like

```
    cboFilterTypes.DataSource = GetDataTable("SELECT ProductType FROM tblProductTypes")
    cboFilterTypes.DisplayMember = "ProductType";
    cboFilterTypes.ValueMember = "ProductType";
```

I wouldn't recommend this way of data access for anythig other than a tiny project.  If you really don't like EF then Dapper or something similar offers a much more scalable solution.  Stackoverflow itself uses Dapper :)

Comment: Of course this doesn't allow the use of parameters. And then, when you need to create some condition in that query, you will be forced to use string concatenation. No good.

Comment: I agree, that's why I said I wouldn't do it this way but was just answering the request for a simple wrapper.

Comment: Thanks I'll check out Dapper. So from what I can see, that's pretty much what I'm looking for